# HEX decoding in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, codec

In Python 2.x I'm able to do this:

```
>>> '4f6c6567'.decode('hex_codec')
'Oleg'
```

But in Python 3.2 I encounter this error:

```
>>> b'4f6c6567'.decode('hex_codec')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    b'4f6c6567'.decode('hex_codec')
TypeError: decoder did not return a str object (type=bytes)
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs#standard-encodings) `hex_codec` should provide "bytes-to-bytes mappings". So the object of byte-string is correctly used here.

How can I get rid of this error to be able to avoid unwieldy workarounds to convert from hex-encoded text?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Python 3, the `bytes.decode()` method is used to decode raw bytes to Unicode, so you have to get the decoder from the `codecs` module using `codecs.getdecoder()` or `codecs.decode()` for `bytes`-to-`bytes` encodings:

```
>>> codecs.decode(b"4f6c6567", "hex_codec")
b'Oleg'
>>> codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")(b"4f6c6567")
(b'Oleg', 8)
```

The latter function seems to be missing from the documentation, but has a useful docstring.

You might also want to have a look at `binascii.unhexlify()`.

Comment: Hm. Then why doesn't AttributeError rise?

Comment: @ovgolovin: Sorry, I was confused.  Corrected now.

Comment: Thank you! I think that the error message generated by Python deserves to be more eloquent because now it's not obvious what the heck is wrong.