# Convert STDOUT hex output to string in Python

Tags: python, string, hex

I've looked for ways to convert the following type of hex output to string characters in Python. The output comes from `STDOUT` earlier in my code and I want to be able to process it further.

Let me give you some examples of the string I want converted:

```
\x5f\x63\x6c\x6f\x73\x65\x28
```

I want this type of string to be stripped of '\x' and I am only interested in the two hex characters that follow. Preferably, I would like to convert strings like this into;

```
5f 63 6c 6f 73 65 28
```

The original input is interpreted as a string, but I am not able to simply strip the `\x` in Python itself. It would be great if I can solve this conversion internally within Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just use basic string functions:

```
s = r'\x5f\x63\x6c\x6f\x73\x65\x28'
s.replace(r'\x', ' ').lstrip()
# '5f 63 6c 6f 73 65 28'

# or
s[2:].replace(r'\x', ' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> '\x12\x34\x56\x78'.encode('hex')
'12345678'
```

Answer (score 2):

For `Python 3` this can be done this way:

```
>>> s = b'\x5f\x63\x6c\x6f\x73\x65\x28'
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(s)
b'5f636c6f736528'
```

`encode` returns an error in Python 3 as convertion is carried from binary-string to binary-string.

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384583/hex-decoding-in-python-3-2) where I faced this problem myself sometime ago.